# Weak and Weak-* L1 convergence

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis

I'm reading a book that says $w^{\epsilon} \rightarrow w$ in the $L^1(Q)$ weak-* sense when

$$\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0} \int_Q w^{\epsilon}f \, dx = \int_Q w f\, dx \quad\forall f \in C_0^{\infty}$$

But is $L^1(Q)$ the dual $C_0^{\infty}(Q)$? I don't remember seeing this anywhere. I think distributions are dual to $C_0^{\infty}(Q)$.

Also what is $w^{\epsilon} \rightarrow w$ $L^1(Q)$ weak convergence? What is dual to $L^1(Q)$?

Comment: Could you say what is $Q$?

Comment: As Banach space $L_1$ is the dual of $L_\infty$ (presumably $Q$ is open in $R^n$ and the measure is Lebesgue's). The dual of $L_\infty$ is much bigger that $L_1$. It is however very useful to consider the weak topology $\sigma(L_\infty,L_1)$ on $L_\infty$ in which case $(L_\infty,\sigma(L_\infty,L_\infty))'= L_1$. The space $C^\infty_0$ is dense in $L_\infty$ with respect the $\sigma(L_\infty,L_1)$ topology.

Comment: In general if $X$ is a linear space and $Y$ is linear space of linear functionals on $X$ that separate points, the weak topology $\sigma(X,Y)$ is the smallest topology on $X$ that make functions in $Y$ continuous. Under this topology, the dual of $X$ is $Y$. $(X,\sigma(X,Y))$ becomes a locally convex topological linear space.

Comment: The dual to L1(Q) is L∞(Q). The space L1(Q) is itself not the dual space of a normed space. This can be shown using Krein Milman theorem.

Comment: The dual of $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}_{00}(Q)$ (also known as the space of distributions) contains $L_1(Q)$ but it is much bigger.

Comment: @OliverDíaz in your first sentance are $L_{\infty}$ and $L_1$ switched (also see Daw's comment)? Also what is the notation $(L_{\infty},\sigma(L_{\infty},L_{\infty})'$ mean?

Comment: @GiulioR Presume that Q is an open set on R^n with Leb msr -- sorry I didn't state this.

Comment: @yoshi: When $L_1$ is given the weak topology $\sigma(L_1,L_\infty)$. The net $f^\epsilon\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}f$ in $\sigma(L_1,L_\infty)$ if $\int f^\varepsilon g\xrightarrow{\varepsilon\rightarrow0}\inf fg$ for all $g\in L_\infty$. However, in your posting you are considering only $g\in C^\infty_0(\Omega)$. The weak convergence in your posting seems more appropriate in  space of distributions $\mathcal{D}'_G$ with the weak topology $\sigma(\mathcal{D}'_G, \mathcal{C}^\infty_{00}(G))$.

Comment: @yoshi: $L_1$ is the dual of $L_\infty$ under the weak topology $\sigma(L_\infty,L_1)$. That is the smallest topology that makes the functionals on $L_\infty$ given by $g\mapsto \int fg$, where $f\in L_1$. This does not contradict Daws comment.